combine Glove and Bert in one model classification
Can I send the word embedding resulting from the Glove and BERT methods to a model such as BiLSTM for word classification?
I tried to unify the length of the embedding resulting from the two methods, but unfortunately it failed, so I would like to confirm whether it is possible to do this or not.
